# CASE WHEN PARTITION BY - Returning Value for Groups with Two Specific Values in Same Column Across Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

As the title says, I'm having trouble returning groups that have two specific values across the group in the same column.

Here is an example of the data:

```
Claim | Exposure | Product
1       1          B
1       2          C
2       1          B
2       2          D
```

My goal is essentially create a third column that specifies if a Claim has a Product = B for any of it's exposures and a Product = C for any of it's exposures (i.e. "All required present"). If the claim is missing an exposure with a specific product, I want to return something like "Product C missing."

Ideally it would result in the following:

```
Claim | Exposure | Product | RequiredCheck
1       1          B         All Required
1       2          C         All Required
2       1          B         Missing C
2       2          D         Missing C
```

I've tried to use a `GROUP BY Claim HAVING Product = B and Product = C`, but this isn't working because the check is based on the same column across a group of claims, and I don't necessarily want to limit my results to only those with "All Required" values.

I've also try to use a `MAX(CASE WHEN Product = B and Product = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PARTITION BY Claim)` but that also wouldn't return any results because the check is based on a value in the same column.

I have thought about coding the products to be a specific number (i.e A = 1, B = 2) and then using `SUM OVER PARTITION BY`, but this also won't work because I could have a claim with multiple exposures with the same product and I can't just say where the count > 5 because it could have 5 exposures with the product A.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case` with window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when num_b > 0 and num_c > 0 then 'All required'
             when num_b > 0 then 'C missing'
             when num_c > 0 then 'B missing'
             else 'Both missing'
        end) as requiredcheck
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when product = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by claim) as num_b,
             sum(case when product = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by claim) as num_c
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: You're my hero! Thank you so much, this did the trick!